# How to send traffic with testpmd to openvswitch when ovs is using dpdkvhostuserclient on baremetal

Tags: linux

Assuming that you have openvswitch installed and running in dpdk mode.
How do you send traffic with dpdk-testpmd to openvswitch when ovs is using a dpdkvhostuserclient interface on baremetal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directory for your dpdkvhostuserclient socket
`mkdir -p /run/openvswitch/host/`
Add a bridge in netdev mode
`ovs-vsctl add-br br-5 -- set bridge br-5 datapath_type=netdev`
Add dpdkvhostuserclient interface to the bridge, note socket will not be created yet
`ovs-vsctl add-port br-5 vhost-user-1 -- set Interface vhost-user-1 type=dpdkvhostuserclient options:vhost-server-path=/run/openvswitch/host/host-net1`

Start testpmd in interactive mode
`./build/app/dpdk-testpmd -l 6,8 --vdev "net_virtio_user0,path=/run/openvswitch/host/host-net1,server=1,queue_size=2048" --in-memory --single-file-segments --no-pci -- -i`
At this point the interface should be up and connected. This can be verified in the dpdk-testpmd terminal with:
`show port info all`
To start traffic in the dpdk-testpmd terminal type:
`set fwd txonly` followed by `start`
To check if packets are been transmitted in testpmd run:
`show port stats 0`
To check if packets are been revived in ovs, in a new terminal run:
`ovs-ofctl dump-ports br-5`